# ERROR WHILE INSERTING USING MYSQLI

Tags: php, html

i'm new to this PHP please help me here i'm unable to insert values into table.
But if i gave values directly to insert command in place of variables it works.

```
<?php
include ("db.php"); 
$msg = "";
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $name);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $email);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
    $password = md5($password);
    $sql="SELECT email FROM users2 WHERE email='$email'";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        $msg = "Sorry...This email already exist...";
    }
    else
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users2 (name, email, password)VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password')");
        if($query)
        {
            $msg = "Thank You! you are now registered.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: **this query**?

Comment: @nogad op didn't format their code. always best to hit the edit button first when that comes up

Comment: @Memor-X its not my job, post properly, or dont bother

Comment: is the form using post? we probably need to see that

Comment: @nogad true but sometimes it's as simple as a missing linebreak (as was the case here when i was about to submit the edit before the OP submitted theirs). other times the asker just didn't post anything at all and expect us to have supernatrual powers to enter their minds. i'd say if it's the former let them know

Comment: your given an *exact* preview when you ask, your to lazy to look, i'm to lazy to answer

Comment: have you tried `var_dump`ing `$_POST` making sure that `$_POST["submit"]` is set and that the values your trying to insert is correct and what you expect

Comment: @Memor-X u mean to say should i use var_dump???
Where?

Comment: @AddalaShivateja i mean use `var_dump` to output `$_POST` to the screen and check it's data yourself. where? anywhere where you'll see the results

Comment: @Memor-X Yeah when i use var_dump it gives me exact output of what i've entered. but it isn't affecting the table

Comment: @AddalaShivateja are you getting you message after the insert?

Comment: @Memor-X Noo i'm not getting that message..
it just gives me blank page.

Comment: @Memor-X  
actually when i substitute thes PHP variables with some names then they are getting inserted into table bt if i'm trying to insert $name like variables there is no o/p.

Comment: @AddalaShivateja if your thank you message isn't appearing then that code isn't being executed properly, especially if by setting hardcoded values makes it work. echo [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to check for my mysql errors with your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users2 (name, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            if (!$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
            die($db->error);
            }
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $email, $password);
            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            die($stmt->error);
            }
```

I don't know what is the problem in my above question but
i used the above query instead of the one i used the in question and Boom it is a success.
if any one of you know whats the problem in the question please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

You have to concat the variable in string of insert not just put as variable

`$query = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO users2 (name, email, password)VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$password."')")`

or

`$query = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO users2 (name, email, password)VALUES ('{$name}', '{$email}', '{$password}')")`

You should use prepare statement for this [mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements](https://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html)

Never use `md5()` [is-md5-considered-insecure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)

Prefer `password_hash()` or `password_verify()` [Manuel](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

``

Comment: Regarding your first point ~ http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: try `mysqli_error($db)` [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: actually when i substitute thes PHP variables with some names then they are getting inserted into table 
bt if i'm trying to insert $name like variables there is no o/p. @gaurav